# I am not able to retrieve value from php array

Tags: php

Here is the code:

I am not able to print the site type in the second function. I am able to print the array when sending "all" as a parameter from a different function.

```
function site_type_find($site_type)
{
 $site_type_name_array=['Youtube','Wikipedia','Mashable','Wired'];
  if($site_type="all")
  return $site_type_name_array;
  else
  return $site_type_name_array[$site_type];
}
function display_topic_category_sitetype($topic_id,$category_id,$site_type)
{
  $result=mysql_query("select topic_name from topic_table where topic_id=$topic_id");
  $result1=mysql_query("select category from categorytable where category_id=$category_id");
  $site_type_name=site_type_find($site_type);
  $resultarr=array();
  $resultarr1=array();
  $resultarr=mysql_fetch_array($result);
  $resultarr1=mysql_fetch_array($result1);
  $topic=$resultarr[0];
  $catname=$resultarr1[0];
?>
  <section>
  <header><?php echo $topic."\n";?></header>
  <article><?php echo $catname."\n";?></article>
  <article><?php echo $site_type_name."\n";?></article>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `==` instead of `=` as the comparison operator.

That's in the 4th line:

```
if($site_type="all") // use two =
```

Comment: thank you for the answer!! Couldn't figure out such a simple thing! :(

Answer (score 5):

Use `==` instead of `=` as a comparison operator.

At line 4, use below code.

```
if($site_type=="all")
```

Where:

`==` is used for `checking equality` OR for `comparison` purpose.

`=` is used for `assigning values` to php variables.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
if($site_type="all")
```

to

```
if($site_type=="all")
```

Answer (score 1):

A single equals operator (`=`) is an assignment operator and A double equals operator (`==`) is a comparison operator,so you have to use `if($site_type=="all")` bcoz here you are comparing the value of `$site_type` with all